# Creating Data models in cassandra using Django

Tags: django, django-models, cassandra, pycassa

How data model creates in cassandra using Django backend?
I have refered twissandra , but i'm confused with how the datamodel created(like in a relational database)

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

look at https://github.com/thobbs/twissandra/blob/master/tweets/management/commands/sync_cassandra.py

You will get a clear picture